# alternatives for tree in web with jsf?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a list with the objects of the class "Test";

```
List<Test> testList;
```

The class Test itself contains a list, too:

```
public class Test {
   private List<Test> children;
   ...
}
```

Now i want to display the testList and being able to choose the objects. When i click(choose) one object, the children of it should be displayed as well.

So far im working with a tree. But I want to use an alternative. Is there one more suitable and better looking for web?

Comment: This kind of poll questions doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. I suggest to reframe your question to describe the concrete problem(s) which you have with your current approach. Then we may be able to answer how to solve them and if necessary suggest better ways in form of alternatives.

Comment: well.. my problem is that this lists can get very long and i just have an limited box, where this view should be shown.. so with a tree its getting difficult to oversee the objects. I already checked some showcases to get some idea, but didnt had luck. Sorry.. if this is still to general.

Comment: Try Tree table with scrollbars